# What is a simple way to play a .wav file in Nim on OSX?

Tags: macos, audio, nim-lang

I am trying to play a `wav` file in a very simple program that looks like this, currently attempting to use [nim-csfml](https://github.com/BlaXpirit/nim-csfml):

```
import csfml_audio

var alarmsong = newMusic("alarm.wav")
alarmsong.play()
```

but it appears to be relying on the existence of `libcsfml.audi`o, and while my program compiles just fine, when I try to actually run it I get an error

```
| => ./alarm
could not load: libcsfml-audio.so
```

(I have a `libcsfml-audio.dylib` instead, being that I used the OSX shared libraries for `csfml/sfml`)

Is there some other way to play a `.wav` file in `Nim`?

---

**Edit 1:**

After the PR made by @def-, I now get a different, slightly more comforting error, which is probably due to some poor understanding of how nim deals with shared libraries:

```
| => ./alarm
could not load: libcsfml-audio.dylib
```

I added `path = "/usr/local/lib"` to my `nim.cfg` file, but it didn't seem to be affect anything. I also exported `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/local/lib"` (`/usr/local/bin` is where `libcsfml-audio.dylib` is.), and tried compilation through

```
nim c alarm.nim --clib:/usr/local/lib/libcsfml-audio.dylib
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3):

For nim-csfml to work you'll need SFML 2.1 and CSFML 2.1. Also, it seems that nim-csfml is actually broken for Mac OS X, so I've made a pull request with a fix: https://github.com/BlaXpirit/nim-csfml/pull/4

Other modules that could play sound are [sdl_mixer](http://nim-lang.org/sdl_mixer.html), [sdl2/audio](https://github.com/nim-lang/sdl2/blob/master/src/sdl2/audio.nim) and [allegro5](https://github.com/fowlmouth/allegro5).

As an OSX-only alternative without using any libraries, by calling the `afplay` binary:

```
import osproc
discard execProcess("afplay", ["file.wav"])
```

**Edit1:**

When Nim reports "could not load: libcsfml-audio.dynlib" that could also mean that one of the dependencies of that library are missing or in a wrong version. Especially SFML 2.2 doesn't work with CSFML 2.1. Make sure libsfml-audio.dynlib is in your LD_LIBRARY_PATH as well. If that doesn't work either, you could try to compile and run a regular C CSFML example like this one: https://gist.github.com/def-/fee8bb041719337c8812

Compile it with `clang -o mainpage -lcsfml-graphics -lcsfml-audio -lGL -lGLEW mainpage.c` to see the errors/warnings about missing libraries.

Comment: Thanks for the advice and thanks for the PR. I was wondering if there was some way to do it that didn't involve just executing a process though, which is why I wanted to use csfml (which is still not working).

Answer (score 3):

This program would just exit immediately; you need to keep it alive while the sound plays. Append this to the program:

```
import csfml_system

while alarmsong.status == SoundStatus.Playing:
  sleep 100.milliseconds
```