# How to play a WAV file in nim?

Tags: audio, nim-lang

I've spent the last few hours working through many different audio libraries found on `nimble.directory` but they are either lacking in documentation or are years old or both.

I'm just getting started with nim, and I'm building a super lightweight audio metronome. I have the timing worked out, but I still need to be able to dump a bytestream to the audio device OR even load a .wav file and play it to an audio device.

I have had some small success with the sdl2 library, but it feels like overkill loading a full game library for this tiny use case.

Can I get some guidance here?

Comment: I know about https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28596986/what-is-a-simple-way-to-play-a-wav-file-in-nim-on-osx, but it is so old, that the description there doesn't help me.

Answer (score 1):

There's [nimbass](https://github.com/genotrance/nimbass) which is a wrapper for the [Bass](http://www.un4seen.com/) library. There's also a wrapper for [Soloud](https://github.com/jarikomppa/soloud) here as part of the nimterop [test](https://github.com/genotrance/nimterop/blob/master/tests/tsoloud.nim) suite that you could try.

Note I haven't personally used either to play a wav file but both provide facilities to do so. [Here's](http://sol.gfxile.net/soloud/) an example for Soloud which could be easily translated into Nim.

If there's a specific C audio lib you want to use, we can look into helping you wrap it, if it isn't already.

Comment: Those are nice suggestions, and Soloud appears to be a contender, but I'm not only interested in libraries. I need to know how to use them in nim. As I said, I'm just getting started with nim. Creating my own wrapper to call C libraries from nim is not straightforward to a beginner like me. I was hoping there would be an actual nim library with nim documentation.

Comment: I understand your concern but I'm not aware of a Nim native library. That being said, it is quite straightforward to call C once the wrapper is done. Check out [this link](https://gist.github.com/zacharycarter/846869eb3423e20af04dea226b65c18f) for a soloud test called from Nim.

Comment: In addition, if you post specific questions here, in the Nim forum or on irc/gitter, I'm sure you will get the help you need.

Comment: Is "How to play a wav file in Nim?" not specific enough? Is there a more specific way I can pose this question?